# Как скачать из Google Fonts вариативный шрифт в формате WOFF2?

Tags: шрифты, google-fonts

Нужно получить из Google Fonts самое лучшее - вариативный шрифт в формате WOFF2. С помощью прямого скачивания оттуда скачивается вариативный TTF. По ссылкам для CSS там нету вариативного. На сайте google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com нет возможности выбрать и скачать вариативный шрифт.

Похоже нужно или искать возможность хитро выудить нужный шрифт из гугл фонтс или конвертировать TTF в WOFF2. Но я пока не знаю как можно надежно конвертировать вариативный шрифт, чтобы ничего в нем не потерять и не сломать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже сам нашел способ скачать вариативный шрифт из гугл фонтс. Нужно создать ссылку такого типа:
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Commissioner:wght@100..900

Где Commissioner - это название шрифта, а диапазон 100..900 - это минимальный и максимальный вес у этого шрифта. По этой ссылке открывается код CSS, в котором указаны ссылки на скачивание шрифта в WOFF2. Причем файлы разделены на разные диапазоны символов юникода: латинский, латин-расширенный, кириллический и т.д. А когда скачиваешь вариативный шрифт прямо с его страницы на гугл фонтс, то он скачивается одним файлом в TTF.

Если у шрифта есть курсивный вариант, то к ссылке видимо нужно подставить такую конструкцию:
':ital,wght@0..1,100..900' или ':ital,wght@1,100..900'